# How to make an array by jumping over every 1 index

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Hi is there a way to make an array by jumping over every 1 index like
lets say i have an array with objects like this:

```
NSArray *array =[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"id",@"name",@"id",@"name",@"id",@"name"..
```

... and so on,
can i make an array by taking only the **ID** objects and/or **NAMES**.
I'm stuck in this, what i really want to achieve is i want id's to be in the tableview subtitle, and names on tableview title.
any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Thanks you for your help everybody, already got my answer, i couldn't go though NSDictionary because, i'm getting objects from .php. Anyways thank you!

Comment: You can modify the array with dictionary. Each dictionary with keys id and name. It would be more clean

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ids and names separated in two different arrays, you could iterate through the original array, and use mod operator like this.-

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"id",@"name",@"id",@"name",@"id",@"name", nil];
NSMutableArray *ids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i ++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        [ids addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    } else {
        [names addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: you sir, have the correct answer of what i'm looking for thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

First (naive) one:

```
cell.subtitle.text = array[indexPath.row*2];
cell.title.text = array[indexPath.row*2+1];
```

Anyway, a more correct alternative would be to use an array of `NSDictionary`s

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{
    @"id": @"theId", @"name" : @"theName"},
    @"id": @"anotherId", @"name" : @"anotherName"},
    ...];
```

And then

```
cell.subtitle.text = array[indexPath.row][@"id"];
cell.title.text = array[indexPath.row][@"name"];
```

Comment: not exactly what i'm looking for, but thanks! i will sure use this in future.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve by making an array of dictionary objects.

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"Id":1, @"Name":@"UserName1"},@"Id":2, @"Name":@"UserName2"}];
```

And in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method

```
NSDictionary *user = self.array[indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = user[@"Id"];
cell.detailLabel.text = user[@"Name"];
```

Comment: i would have done this way, if i could, but since i get objects from .php they're mixed up, so i need to separate them. but thanks anyway!

Comment: @coiler90 Glad to help you, if you have any control over the webservice as the Server guys to provide it in proper structure. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use 2 arrays from the start? If you have to split the arrays, an easy way would be to do it on even and odd numbers.

```
NSArray *array =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"id",@"name",@"id",@"name",@"id",@"name",nil];

NSArray *ids = [array objectsAtIndexes:[array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return ((idx % 2) == 0);
}]];

NSArray *names = [array objectsAtIndexes:[array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return ((idx % 2) != 0);
}]];
```

Comment: i couldn't use two arrays since im getting objects from .php so they kinda mix up together, anyways thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Many answers will just suggest using some other data structure which is recommended if you can. But assuming you have such an array and need to do this its not hard. You could process the array into two - potentially a lot of copying; or you could simply take a view of the array - which trades a smidgin in access time for copying. Here is `JASArray` **with absolutely no checking code** (that is left to you):

```
@interface JASArray : NSArray

- (id) initWith:(NSArray *)baseArray jumpTo:(NSUInteger)jumpTo strideBy:(NSUInteger)strideBy;

@end
```

To override `NSArray` you only need to implement `count` and `objectAtIndex:`:

```
@implementation JASArray
{
   NSUInteger jump;
   NSUInteger stride;
   NSArray *base;
}

- (id) initWith:(NSArray *)baseArray jumpTo:(NSUInteger)jumpTo strideBy:(NSUInteger)strideBy
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self)
   {
      base = baseArray;
      jump = jumpTo;
      stride = strideBy;
   }
   return self;
}

- (NSUInteger) count
{
   return 1 + (base.count - jump - 1) / stride;
}

- (id) objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
   return [base objectAtIndex:(jump + index * stride)];
}

@end
```

Now a test, note the on purpose mismatch pairs as a test:

```
NSArray *array =@[ @"id1", @"name1", @"id2", @"name2", @"id3", @"name3", @"id4" ];
JASArray *ids = [[JASArray alloc] initWith:array jumpTo:0 strideBy:2];
JASArray *names = [[JASArray alloc] initWith:array jumpTo:1 strideBy:2];
NSLog(@"%@\n%@\n%@", array, ids, names);
```

Output:

```
JumpAndStride[10480:303] (
    id1,
    name1,
    id2,
    name2,
    id3,
    name3,
    id4
)
(
    id1,
    id2,
    id3,
    id4
)
(
    name1,
    name2,
    name3
)
```

HTH

Comment: At least in the case of the solutions posted above, none involve any actual copying of data contained in the array. The same pointers to the elements in the original array are used in the new arrays.

Comment: @Andrew - A copying solution requires creating a new structure and the copying of each pointer, I wasn't thinking of a *deep copy*!If the request was "I have data intertwined in an array and need to select *n* elements at random indices" what is best, copying or a view? What solution suits is dependent on application, but a simple view of another structure can be useful - it's just another tool to add to your kit.